# Linked List search method

Tags: linked-list

I am practicing build a doubly linked list contains string value.

In find method, I have a NullPointer Exception

here is my code.

```
package LinkedList;



package LinkedList;

public class LinkedList {

// 노드 클래스
class Node {
    String value;
    Node prev;
    Node next;

    Node(String v, Node p, Node s) {

        value = v;
        prev = p;
        next = s;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public Node getPrev() {
        return prev;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setPrev(Node p) {
        prev = p;
    }

    public void setNext(Node n) {
        next = n;
    }

}

Node head;
Node tail;
int size = 0;

public LinkedList() {
    head = new Node(null, null, null);
    tail = new Node(null, head, null);
    head.setNext(tail);
}

public int size() {
    return size;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size == 0;
}

public String first() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return head.getNext().getValue();
}

public String last() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return tail.getPrev().getValue();
}

public void addFirst(String value) {
    addBetween(value, head, head.getNext());
}

public void addLast(String value) {
    addBetween(value, tail.getPrev(), tail);
}

public void addBetween(String v, Node p, Node s) {
    Node newNode = new Node(v, p, s);
    p.setNext(newNode);
    s.setPrev(newNode);
    size++;
}

public String remove(Node node) {
    Node p = node.getPrev();
    Node s = node.getNext();
    p.setNext(s);
    s.setPrev(p);
    size--;
    return node.getValue();
}

public String removeFirst() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return remove(head.getNext());
}

public String removeLast() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return remove(tail.getPrev());
}

public void insert(String value) {
    Node current = head;
    // first
    if (isEmpty()) {
        addFirst(value);
    } else {
        // check
        while (current.getNext() != tail || current.getValue().compareTo(value) > 0) {
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        // last
        if (current.getNext() == tail) {
            addLast(value);
        } else // between
        {
            addBetween(value, current.getNext(), current);
        }

    }
}

/* !!!!!!!!!!!!!! ERORR !!!!!!!!!!!! */
public void find(String value) {

    Node current = head.getNext();

    while ((current != null) || !(current.getValue().equals(value)))

        current = current.getNext();

    if (current.getValue().equals(value)) {
        System.out.println("found " + value);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not found " + value);
    }

}

// • Traverse the list forwards and print
// 순회
public void fowardTraverse() {
    Node current = head.getNext();

    System.out.print(current.getValue());

    while (current.getNext() != tail) {
        current = current.getNext();
        System.out.print(" -> " + current.getValue());
    }

}

// • Traverse the list backwards and print
// 뒤로 순회
public void backwardTraverse() {

    Node current = tail.getPrev();

    System.out.print(current.getValue());

    while (current.getPrev() != head) {
        current = current.getPrev();
        System.out.print(" -> " + current.getValue());
    }

}

// • Delete a node from the list
     // 지우기
     public String delete(String value) {
        return value;
    }

    // • Delete/destroy the list
    // 파괴하기
    public void destroy() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stubs

        LinkedList a = new LinkedList();
        a.insert("a");
        a.insert("b");
        a.insert("c");
        a.insert("d");
        a.insert("e");
        a.insert("f");
        a.insert("g");
        a.insert("h");
        a.insert("i");
        // a.fowardTraverse();
        a.find("a");

    }
```

I don't understand why I get a nullpointException at the line,

It suppose to put a node contains a.

Comment: Check if `current.getValue()` is not null

Answer (score 0):

*Make sure you check for Non-NULL before dereferencing:*

```
Node current = head.getNext();
```

and

```
if (current.getValue().equals(value)) {
```

to be replaced by

```
Node current; 
if(head != NULL) current = head.getNext();
```

and

```
if (current != NULL && current.getValue().equals(value)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your Head is empty...(No pun intended)
before Addfirst calling..your structure:
head=[null,null,tail],tail=[null,head,null];
you are sending ("a",head,tail)
and your storing it in new node making it a structure like:
head=[null,null,newNode]==>newNode["a",head,tail]==>tail[null,newNode,null]

So search will compare null to a (in find) giving you the error .....
---Edit 1:
@JanghyupLee, My Bad, Didn't do a closer look on find method...however , I  found that in condition of "if" you are using condition

```
 current != null  || ......
```

After first line that is ( current=head.next)..current becomes not null..

which is causing  the condition in while to ignore the right part of '||' (short circuit) until current has a value of null...

Once the current becomes null then it goes for the next statement to check for value..causing null pointer exception

Comment: So I guess, head is null, but I did head.next is assigined in current.  if I am wrong, would you please explain more detail?